# PHP change multiple values of database through checkboxes boolean

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox, material-design-lite

I am trying to make some sort of simple blogging platform and it has been going pretty well until now, my page has a list of articles on it in a table it gets that list from my SQL database and there is also a column which states if the article is public or isn't. The problem is I can't get the writing of all these checkboxes as a boolean to work (if checked input 1 else 0). The part I think it goes wrong is:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT postID FROM blog_posts') ;
        $idArray = $stmt->fetch();

        for($i = $idArray; $i > 0; $i--){
            if(document.getElementById($i).checked){
                $public = 1;
            } else {
                $public = 0;
            }

            try {
                $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE blog_posts SET public = :public WHERE postID = '$i) ;
                $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':public' => $public
                    ));
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

The entire code can be found here on [Hastebin](http://hastebin.com/qisotoveyu.xml)

Comment: `document.getElementById($i)` what is that supposed to mean? That is javascript code, not php!!

Comment: You should probably do a javascript script, which adds a true or false value in a hidden input, if you're using a form.

Comment: You prepare a statement and then try to fetch from it without having executed it. Your for loop tries to `--` what would be an array if you had executed your prepared statement successfully. You have JavaScript code in a PHP if condition. You have nested try blocks, each without a catch. Those are the main problems I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name your `public` checkboxes using an array format, so that each one has the id in its name like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="public[<?php echo $postID ?>]">
```

Then you can use this PHP code to do your updates:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // You can use query here instead of prepare if you want all the blog posts
    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT postID FROM blog_posts');

    // fetch the postID from each row in the query result
    while ($id = $stmt->fetchColumn()) {

        // set public based on the submitted value from your form
        $public = empty($_POST['public'][$id]) ? 0 : 1;

        // do the update
        $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE blog_posts SET public = ? WHERE postID = ?') ;
        $stmt->execute(array($public, $id);
    }
}
```

Note that you are `SELECT`ing *every blog post*, so if your form does not include every blog post, this code will set every one that isn't on your form to `public=0`. If you aren't displaying every blog post on your form, you'll need to add a `WHERE` clause to your `SELECT` statement so that it only includes the rows that *are* included in your form.

Comment: Thank you for your help, now I have it working (sort of) the remaining problem is that the while loop I think doesnt loop through every checkbox since I can only edit the checkbox with array index 1 and none of the others: http://hastebin.com/xideferowe.xml full page code and fully loaded page http://hastebin.com/obobituhot.dos also yes all my checkboxes and articles are in the form, I hope you can help me figure the last part out